# UIImageViews - layers

Tags: cocoa-touch, core-animation

I have 2 UIImageViews, IMG1 and IMG2 . Somesomes I want IMG1 to appear above IMG2 , and at other times I want IMG2 to appear above IMG1. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myImageView];
```

Answer (score 3):

Also,

```
[self.view exchangeSubviewAtIndex:imageView1Index withSubviewAtIndex:imageView2Index];
```

might do this, if you know the indices of the respective views.